# "All hopes are gone!"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, countability

Is there any grammatical problem using 'hope' as a plural noun? Can't we say:

> All hopes are gone

I wrote in a sentence but the Grammar software marked it incorrect. It says it has to be:

> All hope is gone.

I heard the plural case in an English movie.

Comment: "That boy is our last hope." "No! There is another."

Comment: While *hope* is typically a mass noun as in "I don't have much hope", it can also be a countable noun, as in "What are your hopes and fears?".

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that "hope", when used to mean "feeling of trust that something wished for will happen"  is generally a non-countable noun.  Nouns that represent emotions tend to be non-count, eg "anger", "joy", "disgust".

The countable form refers to the thing wished for, or (usually singlar) a particular instance of the feeling.  It is possible to say "All hopes are gone", but it is odd and not the usual expression, and it is useful for the software to flag such an expression for human review.